# Heal selection not working on Gimp 2.10.10 (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: gimp

[image: a]

I added these files inside the plug-ins folder and made sure they all were executable and able to Read and Write. I opened GIMP but **Heal Selection didn't appear under Filters>Enhance**

I installed gimp with:

**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp**

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install gimp**

I got the information from https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Gimp-2-10-Resynthesizer-Linux

Is it possible to add the resynthesizer to 2.10.10? Why doesn't it work?

Every article i've read about this are years old and use an older version of GIMP.

Comment: Do you have the `gimp-plugin-registry` installed? That's all I need to get the heal tool working under Image> Enhance.

Comment: I don't think so, how do I do that? sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry?

Comment: Yes, it should bring in `gimp-gmic` automatically. Then just load `gimp` and try to do a heal.

Comment: Just installed it it did change gimp up a little bit, but, I opened gimp and it's still not there.. it's under Filters>Enhance, right? There is no Enhance under Image on mine..

Comment: Nevermind, just had to do "sudo apt install gimp-python" and it works now, thanks for your support!

Comment: You can post that as answer :)

Comment: Aye, it looks like it's a new package in Disco, https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/amd64/gimp-python/filelist, previously those files were in the normal gimp package AFAICT. Might actually be a bug, `sudo apt install gimp` should raise gimp-python as a "recommends".

Answer (score 0):

In my case GIMP 2.10.18 (as of April 2020), steps I have to do are:

1. Get Executable file. Download **resynth-linux.zip** from [the link here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Gimp-2-10-Resynthesizer-Linux?pid=11261#pid11261). Then extract, there you just have to copy resynthesizer and resynthesizer_gui file to your plugins folder.
2. Get the plugin, you can either copy the two files in the downloaded file above which are plugin-heal-selection.py and plugin-heal-transparency.py, or if you want more, you can download then extract from the [source git code here](https://github.com/pixlsus/registry.gimp.org_static/blob/master/registry.gimp.org/files/resynthesizer.tar_0.gz), then copy the python files to your gimp plugin folder.
3. **Allow executing file as program.** On each python file, right click -> *Properties* -> *Permissions* -> Tick "Allow executing file as program". [Reference here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-How-to-install-Gimp-Heal-Plugin-Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is to install the appimage version. https://appimage.github.io/GIMP/

An alternative solution (which worked for me) is that taken from the Gimp forum (June 2020) https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Heal-Selection-Missing-from-Gimp-on-Ubuntu-20-04?pid=18351#pid18351.
This is for the **deb version of Gimp 2.10.18-1 on Ubuntu 20.04** (there are flatpack and snap versions too).
Take into account that future updates might correct the issue. The problem with the deb version of Gimp (in Ubuntu 20.04) appears to be that python integration is missing.  The code below installs packages from Ubuntu 18.10.

```
sudo apt install python2.7

sudo apt install python python-cairo python-gobject-2

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gimp/gimp-python_2.10.8-2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry
```

Comment: Maybe adding some explanation about what is happening here be helpful.

Comment: The last command is sufficient, no need in all the magic with separate `*.deb` files. I've simply installed `gimp-plugin-registry` and got the _Heal Selection_ menu item.

Comment: Take into account I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and installed the deb version from the synaptic package manager.  There are snap and flatpack versions too.  Just adding gimp-plugin-registry didn't work for me, the above instructions work for Gimp 2.10.18-1, I'll amend the answer to be more specific. .